# Run content script every time a page loads with Google Extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Google Chrome extension. My extension currently extends the content area and header to make room for another icon in the jewel container (where notifications and friend requests are) and adds the icon. It works fine when the page is first loaded, but when you go to a different page on the site and then back home the layout gets screwed up.

Since this isn't an issue with code (as it works fine the first time the page is loaded), I'd like to know if there's a way to run a content script every single time a page is loaded. Is this possible, or can I inject the Javascript I have into Facebook every time it loads with a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way around this by using `setInterval()` to run the code (or at least the code that wasn't always running) every millisecond.

Apparently, unless I misunderstood, Chrome runs the code once per browser session, so using `setInterval()` is the best alternative. Though, the strange behavior was that Chrome was running part of my code once, and then wasn't after that unless certain circumstances were met.

`setInterval()` worked wonders in this case, though.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it your code properly gets injected every time a page loads but when a user selects a different tab then returns you need the code to run again?

Have a look at the [Page Visibility API](http://w3c-test.org/webperf/specs/PageVisibility/). You can you should be able to listen for the `visibilitychange` event and run your code again.

Comment: Not exactly--switching tabs preserves the results of the code the first time it was injected. What I need is for it to run again when the Facebook button is clicked, or when Home is clicked, from any page on Facebook. For some reason, parts of my script "undo" themselves while others retain the results the injection had the first time.

Comment: Oh so you are talking about when Facebook loads a page with AJAX they break/remove some of your changes? Use [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate) and [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) and check if your changes have been reverted. Add back as needed.

Comment: Both `onpopstate` and `onhashchange` had no effect. In fact, `onhashchange` started screwing up profiles.

Comment: You might just have to check every second to see if `location.pathname` has changed and if it does check your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the script as a Content script at the manifest file. Background pages are only executed once per browser session.

## Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
           "128": "icon128.png"},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["go.js"],
      "all_frames":true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

## Content script file (go.js):

```
// your stuff
```

PS: This method doesn't work on Chrome internal pages...

Comment: I was using it as a content script before, but that was even worse. I changed it to be run from the background page and that made the problem a little better (more often than not it was actually running).